# Unable to use cordova plugin from github in Intel XDK

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I am trying to add cordova plugin at https://github.com/dbaq/cordova-plugin-contacts-phone-numbers in Intel XDK thrid-party plugins. I have given plugin id at `com.dbaq.cordova.contactsPhoneNumbers` and Repo URl as https://github.com/dbaq/cordova-plugin-contacts-phone-numbers.git but even after bulding the whole project for android, when I use `navigator.contactsPhoneNumbers.list` after deviceReady event, I get "`Cannot read property 'list' of undefined`". Is there anything, I am missing. Same thing happens with other cordova plugins located on Github like Cordova CallNumberPlugin located at github.com/Rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin.

Note that, I have tested the build on android phone but still no success.

Comment: Any help is appreciated, I have been trying to make it work from last 4 days but no luck.

Comment: Can you provide a simple project (the www directory and the `<project-name>.xdk` file) that illustrates the problem?